# Why is this C played as an A flat?

Tags: theory, piano, notation, sheet-music

I am puzzled by the left hand of this piece (Kiss the Rain by Yiruma):

[image]

The first note on the lower staff looks like a C to me. However, all video tutorials play it as an A flat (for example [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uXayzi_blGU) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l-Ne6HjoCqY)).

How can this be?

Comment: Notice the *octave* being played in the tutorial. That also should have confused you. If the left hand were notated with the bass clef, the C that note would indicate would be almost two octaves lower than the A being played.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The left hand is in treble clef.

Comment: I think Matt means left hand is in *bass* clef...or is that what's unique here?

Comment: @Tim no. Matt said what he said - left hand, usually in bass clef, is written in treble clef here. It's thus an ordinary A. Right hand is in treble +8. It's just that.

Comment: Not A, it is A flat.

Comment: @Tim look at the G symbol in the beginning of the left hand, it's a treble clef. A bass clef starts with a F symbol, find a normal sheet I'm sure you will see the difference.

Comment: @fdb It’s the A that is diatonic to the key signature, and thus is ordinary. (Who’s gonna out-pedantic THAT?) ;-)

Comment: @NReilingh: "out-pedantic' is not a verb. Out-pedanted.